# Unable to add lexer rule inside tilde(~) in ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have my Lexer grammar as follows:

```
lexer grammar MarkupLexer;

fragment D          : ('D'|'d') ;
fragment O          : ('O'|'o') ;
fragment W          : ('W'|'w') ;
fragment N          : ('N'|'n') ;
fragment L          : ('L'|'l') ;
fragment A          : ('A'|'a') ;
fragment S          : ('S'|'s') ;
fragment Y          : ('Y'|'y') ;
fragment H          : ('H'|'h') ;
fragment U          : ('U'|'u') ;
fragment T          : ('T'|'t') ;


OPEN                : '[' -> pushMode(BBCODE) ;

GETFILE             : D O W N L O A D ;
SAYS                : S A Y S ;
SHOUTS              : S H O U T S ;

TEXT                : ~('[' | GETFILE)+ ;

// Parsing content inside tags
mode BBCODE;



CLOSE               : ']' -> popMode ;
SLASH               : '/' ;
EQUALS              : '=' ;
STRING              : '"' .*? '"' ;
ID                  : LETTERS+ ;
WS                  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;

fragment LETTERS    : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

Whereas the Parser grammars is as follows:

```
parser grammar MarkupParser;

options { tokenVocab=MarkupLexer; }

file        : download element* ;

attribute   : ID '=' STRING ;

download    : GETFILE ;

command     : (SAYS | SHOUTS) ;

content     : TEXT ;

element     : (download | command | content | tag) ;

tag         : '[' ID attribute* ']' element* '[' '/' ID ']' ;
```

However, when I execute the following command:

> java org.antlr.v4.Tool -listener -visitor Markup*.g4
>
> I get this particular error: 
>   error(134): MarkupLexer.g4:23:30: rule reference GETFILE is not
>   currently supported in a set

My goal is that TEXT can contain any letters or words, except for "GETFILE"(Download), "SAYS"(says) and "SHOUTS"(shouts).
How can I achieve this??

**EDITED:**
I solved the issue, by editing the parser rule as follows:

```
file        : download element* ;
```

**QUESTION 1:**
How can I add space between download and element?

**QUESTION 2:**
How can I make a rule which says that Name or Table tag could lie anywhere in the input? For-example: “Get Person [Name id=3] John [/Name] from [Table]Employees[/Table]”

Comment: can you possibly also update the g4 files, to match your edit remark?

Comment: Please provide an example of input to parse so we can copy-paste and execute your grammar. Q1 : what do you mean by "add space" ? where ? in the parser rule or the input ? Your WS rule captures spaces and eliminates it. To keep it -> channel(HIDDEN) Q2 : need more examples.

Comment: @CoderX It looks like you solved your own question. However, the text is currently confusing. Please, to help the community here: (1) edit your question to be self-contained, without follow-up questions; (2) add your own answer; (3) select your own answer as correct.